# Listening to a woman giving shiur

Tags: halacha, women, torah-study, tznius-modesty, men-male

Can a man listen to a woman give a shiur (Torah class)? Does it matter if it's not in a class format — like, let's say it's on a CD?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Chaim, and thanks for bringing your question here. Might I suggest you [edit] your question to include what you know, which led you to this question? (Specifically, why do you think this might be forbidden?) See also "[ask]". Anyway, I hope you stick around and enjoy the site, including [its 181 other questions about Torah study](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah-study). You might wish to [register](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account for [more site features](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557).

Comment: @Chaim, 1. Are you asking from a Mussar POV, a Halachic POV? A strict (original) Torah POV?

Comment: @DannySchoemann I understand that I did not ask the question but I think all of the above POVs will be interesting for the users of this site

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1413&st=&pgnum=20&hilite=

Comment: http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/223487/halachically-speaking-kol-isha-and-other-tznius-issues.html   (See [40])

Answer (score 9):

Per [Rabbi Avraham Yosef](http://www.moreshet.co.il/web/shut/shut2.asp?id=138019) it is permitted 100% to listen to a recording of a woman giving a Shiur. However it is prohibited to sit at a Shiur which is being given by a woman.

Comment: Does he explain why he distinguishes between the two cases?

Comment: If listening to music by a woman is permitted all the more so a Shiur (epis?).

Comment: What about a video shiur?

Comment: There is a concept of the yetzer harah not desiring what it cannot see, ive heard that recorded women's singing is permitted if the listener has never seen the singer as well.

Comment: I've seen rav-approved shiurim given by women with men in the audience. Presumably, R' Yosef's opinion is not universally accepted.

Comment: From Igros moshe, orach Chaim, 5, 12, 3.   Should do it in a tsnius way i.e. not in shul and the woman should be sitting (not good that there is mixed sitting)

Comment: @GersonGold: Would it matter if there was only close family listening? How close?

Comment: @DannySchoemann: I imagine this ruling is regarding a non family member, for a public Shiur. However I only know what it says as I did not ask the question personally, so anything beyond my answer would be conjecture.

Comment: Maybe it's related as to why it is prohibited to give a woman an aliyah, because it may disgrace the congregation. I hihgly doubt it though.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot tell from your question if you're concern is focused on Kol Isha. I am assuming that is the focus. [This article](http://www.jewishideas.org/articles/new-hearing-kol-ishah) discusses Kol Isha and when and how it applies, citing various viewpoints. I am citing one of the permissible views. Read the remaining sections of the article, as there are varying opinions.

> Rabbi Yehiel Yaakov Weinberg (Seridei Esh 2:8) defended the
>   German-Jewish custom of mixed-sex zemirot, as well mixed sex Jewish
>   youth groups (similar to Benei Akiva and NCSY).[3] He interpreted the
>   Rambam that the prohibited form of "gazing" and listening is only that
>   which entails sexual pleasure. Rabbi Weinberg also relied on the Sedei
>   Hemed (section Kuf, kelal 42), who ruled that a man's listening to a
>   woman sing funeral dirges does not violate kol ishah, as no sexual
>   pleasure is entailed in such songs. The Sedei Hemed was relying on the
>   Divrei Heifetz (113b), who "stated that as long as a woman is not
>   singing sensual love songs, and as long as a man does not intend to
>   derive pleasure from her voice, there is no prohibition, such as if
>   she is singing praises to God for a miracle, or is singing a lullaby
>   to a baby, or is wailing at a funeral." [4] Rabbi Weinberg also cited
>   the Sefer ha-Eshkol (Hilkhot Tefillah sec. 4 or 7), that listening to
>   a woman sing is prohibited only where there is sexual pleasure. Rabbi
>   Weinberg reasoned that if the Sedei Hemed could permit funeral dirges
>   due to their lacking sexual pleasure, then he could permit Shabbat
>   zemirot on the same grounds. It is obvious that we today can likewise
>   permit by the same logic any song which does not lead to sexual
>   thoughts. Thus, this interpretation that kol ishah is like etzba
>   ketana, i.e. permitted where sexual pleasure is absent, is not only
>   apparent from the simple meaning of Rambam's words, but is also
>   endorsed by Rabbi Yehiel Weinberg.
>
> Rabbi Weinberg also relied on the opinion of the Ritva and Rema, "that
>   all is for the sake of heaven" (to be discussed later in this essay).
>   In general, if one knows that he himself is capable of a certain act
>   without incurring sexual thoughts, then this act becomes permitted for
>   him.

I am inferring from above as well as the rest of the article, that the main concerns are related to singing. As you can see, there are leniencies, there. I think that hearing a woman speak is less of a concern of Kol Isha.

If your concern is regarding mixed seating, I can say from my personal experience, that I have attended numerous services where there was a mechitza for davening. A woman gave the D'var Torah before Musaph on Shabbat, and she went to the front of the shul, and the mechitzah curtain was drawn so that the women could see her. It was a given, then, that the men could see her as well as the other women.